# R, shiny: using ColVis DataTable plugin

Tags: javascript, r, debugging, datatables, shiny

I wish to use the ColVis plugin with DataTable in shiny.

[ColVis](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/)

The plugin provides the user with a nice button/dropdown selection menu to control column visibility.

In my latest attempt to get this working, I have:

- added dataTables.colVis.js to my app's wwww directory
- tried includeScript("www/dataTables.colVis.js")
- also tried tags$head(tags$script(src="dataTables.colVis.js")) as a MainPanel argument
- see no errors, in R, or in the Chrome console
- but see no button providing access to column selection

I am accustomed to debugging javascript, but at a loss here for finding and debugging the javascript created from ui.R by Shiny.

Are there tutorials on how to debug a shiny a shiny app at the level of javascript?
Has anyone had success using ColVis in shiny?
Is there a better, Shiny-native way to allow the user easy access to hide/display DataTable columns?

Thanks,

- Paul

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at new package from RStudio DT (https://github.com/rstudio/DT)? Here http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html you could find an example of what you need.